# Sitecore Workflow implementation on Multiple CD environment

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1, sitecore-workflow

I need a suggestion on how to impliment the workflow in Multiple CD environment.

The current setup of the environments are as below.

- CM
- UAT
- Preprod
- Prod

As of now, Publishing happens from CM to UAT, Preprod and Prod by Smart publishing. Now we want to implement the Workflow to publish the content considering its advantages.

I have a experience in implimenting Workflow, where we have 1 CM and 1 CD environment. Defining the Workflow states here are pretty easy.

1. Draft
2. Awaiting Approval
3. Publish

But in our case, requirement is not same. We would like to have below states.

1. Draft - On `submit`, This workflow should go to Awaiting Approval state.
2. Awaiting Approval  - On `Approval`, Content should be published to UAT.
3. UAT - On click of `Publish to Preprod`, Content should be published to Preprod.
4. Preprod - On click of `Publish to Prod`, Content should be published to Prod.
5. Prod - Auto Publish and Final state. Move to Draft state.

For the above scenario i thought of below User roles. Thanks to nikkiPunjabi for the nice [article](http://blog.nikkipunjabi.com/2014/09/sitecore-workflow-quickstart-guide-part2.html)

- SitecoreEditor
- SitecoreReviewer
- SitecorePublisher

Now my question is, how we can publish the content to UAT and PreProd using workflow as it not the `Final state`. I have read the following [article](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/latest_technical_reinnovations/posts/out-of-the-box-support-for-pre-production-publishing) and tried to implement the same,but the content are publishing to all the environment when it reaches to the final state(Not before that).

Does anyone have past experience in implementing the workflow in this way? If so could you please help me to solve the problem?

Thanks for your help.

https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/latest_technical_reinnovations/posts/out-of-the-box-support-for-pre-production-publishing

Comment: I'm not sure if Stack Overflow is the best place to ask questions like that. I think that answering this one would require lot of discussion and the answer can be really opinion based. Maybe Sitecore Community Slack channel is a better place for this question?

Comment: The article you referenced is the right approach. You need to make sure you enable a preview publishing target, and make sure your workflow states are not 'final' until the very final one.

Comment: Preview publishing target is enabled and i have verified that only prod state is in final state. I have given access restriction to Roles for the Workflow states. Will that make any problem. http://blog.nikkipunjabi.com/2014/09/sitecore-workflow-quickstart-guide-part2.html

Answer (score 0):

I found that, Below article is the right approach to implement the solution. Make sure, You are giving necessary access to Workflow user. Otherwise, content will not get published to specified targets. I will try to update this post with the Users, roles  and access i have given to make it work.

https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/latest_technical_reinnovations/posts/out-of-the-box-support-for-pre-production-publishing